# On device iOS websocket server

Tags: ios, websocket

Looking to implement websockets communication between a UIWebView in iOS with javascript to a local on the device websockets server in objective-c. Anyone seen a sample code set for setting a local websocket server on device for iOS so that the web view half can easily talk to the native container and vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

I have made a websocket server that runs on iOS. It is a wrapper around libwebsockets, the code is on github: https://github.com/benlodotcom/BLWebSocketsServer .

Answer (score 1):

try this library https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer
it has a MAC and IOS example with websockets.